# Method not found: 'Void Amazon.Runtime.Internal.IRequest.set_DisablePayloadSigning(System.Nullable`1<Boolean>)'

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-net

The following code:

```
var _s3Client = new Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);

Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest request = new Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest
{ 
    BucketName = _bucketName, Key = keyName
};

using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
{
    request.InputStream = stream;
    _s3Client.PutObject(request);
}
```

Throws this AmazonS3Exception when calling PutObject function:

> {"Method not found: 'Void
> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.IRequest.set_DisablePayloadSigning(System.Nullable`1)'."}

Full stacktrace:

```
at Amazon.S3.Model.Internal.MarshallTransformations.PutObjectRequestMarshaller.Marshall(PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Marshaller.PreInvoke(IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Marshaller.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ExceptionHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RuntimePipeline.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceClient.Invoke[TResponse](AmazonWebServiceRequest request, InvokeOptionsBase options)
at ParametersRunner.Program.TestAmazons3Client() in <pathToProgram>/Program.cs:line 243"
```

I'm targeting .NET Framework 4.5 & using AWSSDK.S3 v3.3.24.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading AWSSDK.S3 to 3.7.0.32 and installing AWSSDK.Core 3.7.0.31 solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error message, but the root cause of my problem was distinct. The error arose during the initialization of an AmazonSimpleEmailServiceConfig instance. Upon closer inspection, I discovered that various projects within my project solution were using different versions of AWSSDK.Core, leading to the encountered issue